# Host not loading from config file

Tags: ssh, cygwin, openssh

I'm trying to set up a config file for OpenSsh in Cygwin.

In `~/.ssh` I have a `config` file, like this:

```
Host sgn
     HostName mydomain.net
     User uRandomDigits
```

But when I execute `ssh sgn`, I get the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname sgn: hostname nor servname provided, or not known
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Any assistance would be appreciated.  I'm on Windows Vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the `config` file in the wrong place. :P

With Cygwin, the .ssh folder is located in `C:\cygwin\home\{User}\.ssh`, not `C:\Users\{User}`.